# Linking Libraries in android project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am developing one android application and one android library. I have included other third party library in build.gradle of my library.

I want to include my library in my application, build and install the application on my android device. Application is installed successfully, but I got exception like java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, which are related to third party library.

This issue resolved when third party library is included in build.gradle of my application source code.

My question is why third party library will include in application's build.gradle? It is already included in my library.